# Is this the right method to mix PCM audio?

Tags: c#, audio, signal-processing, audio-streaming

I have an assignment to make an audio conference chat room using sockets. Is this the right approach to mix audio?

- `s` is byte array which will be sent to client `cl`.
- `cl.ar` is a byte array that contains PCM samples received from `cl`.
- `ar` is a float array that contains sum of samples from all clients.

I subtract the sample of `cl` from the total sum divide it by number of other logged in users and send it to `cl`.

```
s[i] = (byte)((ar[i] - cl.ar[i]) / (activeClients.Count - 1));
```

Is this the correct way?

Comment: and the language? I also very much doubt your output buffer makes 8-bit signed audio samples.  What is it?

Comment: The language is C#. I'm using NAudio to get microphone input and it is giving me 16 bit each for 2 channels.

Comment: I doubt the division is reasonable. When only one client sends audio, it will effectively get damped just by the bare presence of other clients. I would go with the pure sum (subtracting the client's own audio). Also, watch out for type compatibility. Subtracting a byte from a float may not produce the result you like (watch the signs).